# bulk request size

Tags: java

i have created a restful web service using java which will accept the json records.I would like to know what is the maximum size of the json request so that api can handle? and what is the best way to handle bulk records in rest api request

Answer (score 1):

The raw limit should be the same as the Heap Size limit (currently 6MB). The best way to handle the data would be to parse the JSON, build the records, perform the DML, and return the result, just like you would for any other service. As an alternative, you can also use the [composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) REST resource, which allows 25 records at once, or the [sObject tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm) resource, which handles 200 records at once, or the [sobjects collections](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections.htm) resource, which allow allows deletions, and up to 200 records at once. You may find it more efficient to simply use what's already available than to build your own.